# Creating edges in neo4j based on query results

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I'm modelling a search term transition graph in a e-commerce software as a graph of nodes (terms) and edges (transitions). If a user types e.g. `iphone` in the search bar and then refines the query to `iphone 6s` this will be modeled as two nodes and a edge between those nodes. The same transition of terms of the different users will result in several edges between the nodes.

[image]

I'd now like to create an edge with a cumulated weight of 4 to represent that 4 users did this specific transition. How can I combine the results of a `count(*)` query with a create query to produce an edge with a property `weight = 4`

My `count(*)` query is:

```
MATCH (n:Term)-[r]->(n1:Term)
RETURN type(r), count(*)
```

I'd expect the combined query to look like this, but this kind of sql like composition seems not to be possible in `cypher`:

```
MATCH (n:Term), (n1:Term)
WHERE (n)-[tr:TRANSITION]->(n1)
CREATE (n)-[actr:ACC_TRANSITION {count: 
    MATCH (n:Term)-[r]->(n1:Term) RETURN 
    count(*)}
]->(n1)
RETURN n, n1
```

A non generic query to produce the accumulated transition that works is:

```
MATCH (n:Term), (n1:Term)
WHERE n.term = 'iphone' AND n1.term ='iphone 6s'
CREATE (n)-[actr:ACC_TRANSITION {count: 4}]->(n1)
RETURN n, n1
```

Any other ideas on how to approach and model this problem?

Comment: Use with in first query is count(*) and in second query create your relation

Comment: Can you please formulate the query? How would it look like with the `with`? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I am busy at work and can't explain more my answer for now :)

Answer (score 3):

Use WITH like this:

```
MATCH (n:Term)-[r]->(n1:Term)
WITH n as n, count(*) as rel_count, n1
CREATE (n)-[:ACC_TRANSITION {count:rel_count}]->(n1)
RETURN n, n1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you match the nodes and relationship first and then use set, you will not produce duplicate nodes or relationships

```
Match (n:Term)-[r]->(n1.Term)
with n as nn,count(r) as rel_count,n1 as nn1
set r.ACC_TRANSITION=rel_count
return nn,nn1,r
```

The create function will create duplicates.

Comment: He wants to creat new relation and add property of counts in that relation.